# Wifi widget not working in KDE Plasma 5.12.6 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, widgets

I upgraded my ubuntu desktop from 16.04 to 18.04 and installed KDE on it. Now I can't see wifi network setting widget on my panel. I checked system tray settings but could not find the widget.

Comment: How did you install KDE? Do you have ethernet connectivity?

Comment: yes, I installed using an ethernet connection. Just used apt to install KDE as an alternative to gnome

Comment: What was the exact command you used?

Comment: @DK Bose Sorry for the late reply, I had thesis submissions. This was the command - `sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Install plasma-nm, seems like plasma-desktop does not install it